# Has anyone deployed a embedded service config?

Tags: unlocked-package, einstein-bots, embedded-services

I created a embedded service config for a chatbot using a messaging channel, I am trying to package it (org depended package). I had to include 'customSite, 'Network', and 'StaticResource' metadata files within my package.

When I try to install the package version, it throws an error saying

> In field: PicassoSite - no SiteDotCom named NAME_OF_SITE found, Details: NAME_OF_SITE: In field: PicassoSite - no SiteDotCom named NAME_OF_SITE found

Has anyone been able to create a package with an embedded service? or even deploy it from sandbox to sandbox/prod?